# Неправильная кодировка файлов с русскими буквами в Safari

Tags: кодировка, macos, safari

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал менять в настройках кодировку, ничего не изменилось

Помогите, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Где конкретно в Safari? Откуда эти файлы берутся? Вы уверены, что в проблеме виноват этот Safari, а не кто-нибудь другой, портящий кодировку ещё до попадания в Safari?

Comment: @andreymal При скачивании файла (откуда угодно). Уверен, что Safari, потому что на Chrome такой проблемы нет